# Can last be a synonym for least?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, figures-of-speech

My thought process is that I can be **first among equals** but can I also be **last among equals** and can this be extended to just be a general **the best** and **the worst**. That would mean **I am the first and you are the last *X*** could also be interpreted as **I am the best and you are the worst *X***?

Comment: And what have you found when you looked in dictionaries?

Comment: @PeterShor neither last nor first really mention it, unless you count first's "The one coming, occurring, or ranking before or above all others.", which, to me, doesn't necessarily sound 100% applicable

Comment: The words are not  interchangeable.  "I was least in line" doesn't work. But it's possible to state pretty much the same meaning, or at least a closely related meaning, using either word but with different phrasing.   He was the least likely to volunteer. He was always the last to volunteer.

Comment: @TimRonadifferentdevice I know that synonyms are not universals. Tongue can mean language (for example mother tongue) but language cannot be the body part. I was wondering about this exact case, can You're the last repuvlican mean that you are the worst repuvlican or is it limited to the latest one?

Comment: Least does not mean latest.  Nor does it mean "worst".  "The least X" means "embodying the characteristics of X in the smallest degree".

Comment: *Last* can mean *least likely* — "He was the last person you'd have thought would write a book." But if you pick a random sentence with "least" in it and replace it with "last", you don't get a  sentence that means the same thing. For example, "the least of his enemies" and "the last of his enemies" mean two quite different things.

Comment: We sometimes use the expression **last but not least** to indicate that the fact that something happens to be mentioned last in a list _doesn't_ mean that it is the least important.

Comment: "First among equals" does not mean "best."

Comment: "First among equals" is a play on words for describing a particular situation (where someone is nominally equal but in practice has greater power than those they are theoretically equal with); it's become a set phrase for referring to certain people. But "last among equals" isn't used in the same sense. This has nothing to do with being the best and the worst.

Comment: @StuartF if you make the part about the set phrase an answer, I'll accept it